# PHP Datetime check date with different format

Tags: php, datetime

I've got a problem with datetime condition checked.

First, I've a DateTime value that stored in database as `2018-05-08 15:54:40`

But, I want to check only date is equal or not.

For example:

```
$DateInDatabase = 2018-05-08 15:54:40
$DateSpecific = 2018-05-08

if ($DateInDatabase == $DateSpecific) {
   ......
}
```

The question is how to check only date in `$DateInDatabase`

Comment: if you just want to compare the dates if they are equal you can do it also in the non-orthodox way: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php `if( false === strpos($DateInDatabase, $DateSpecific)){ //not equal} else { //equal}` based that your fomrat of the `Y-m-d` remains as it is.

Comment: If you found an answer to your question, please mark whichever helped you as the "accepted answer" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only interested in the year-month-day, my suggestion would be something such as;

```
// As per comments, the second param in the date function MUST be a UNIX timestamp, so strtotime will resolve this
$dateInDB = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($DateInDatabase)); // format to XXXX-XX-XX
$dateToCheck = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($DateSpecific)); // format to XXXX-XX-XX

if ($dateInDb == $dateToCheck)
{
    // They are the same
}
else
{
    // The are different
}
```

As others have said, you can use direct string comparison also;

```
$DateInDatabase = "2018-05-08 15:54:40";
$DateSpecific = "2018-05-08";

// This function uses the params haystack, needle in that order
if (stristr($DateInDatabase, $DateSpecific)) 
{
   // Match found
}
else
{
    // No match found
}
```

Comment: But the condition is I can't change format of DateTime from database

Comment: @B.Godoak - you can have 2 variables, one with the original, and one with the Y-m-d formatted

Answer (score 0):

This will check if your dates are equal. Be aware that PHP's `date` function has a limit in how far you can go for the year. The minimum is  `01-01-1970` and the maximum is `19-01-2038` (`d-m-Y` format used here). The date is converted to an integer (`strtotime`). If those numbers are equal, the dates are equal.

```
$DateInDatabase = '2018-05-08 15:54:40'
$DateSpecific = '2018-05-08'

$newDate1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($DateInDatabase));
$newDate2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($DateSpecific));


if ($newDate1 == $newDate2) {
   //equal
} else {
  //not equal
}
```

Comment: The limit on the date is 1971(maybe 1970?)-01-01 as this is UNIX epoch, just for future ref :)

Comment: The 2038 limit is if you are using 32 bit PHP, 64 bit does allow further but is as yet somewhat incomplete

Answer (score 0):

You can use php date method to format date:

```
$DateInDatabase ='2018-05-08 15:54:40';
$DateSpecific = '2018-05-08';

if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($DateInDatabase)) == $DateSpecific) {
  echo 'ok';
} else {
  echo 'not ok';
}
```

Read more about php date method from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can either directly match as string or parse as date and later format as string.

Given that `$DateInDatabase = '2018-05-08 15:54:40'` and `$DateSpecific = '2018-05-08'`

```
if (false !== strpos($DateInDatabase,$DateSpecific)) {
   /* matched */
}
```

OR

```
$format = 'Ymd';
$DateInDatabase = (new DateTime($DateInDatabase))->format($format);
$DateSpecific = (new DateTime($DateSpecific))->format($format);
if ($DateInDatabase === $DateSpecific) {
   /* matched */
}
```